# Dashboard - Server not reachable: unauthorized

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

My dashboard and apps have been working fine for the last few months and today it suddenly stopped working. I have reconfigured everything 
All config file keys match and nginx seems to be correct to look at my correct conf.d file. Restarted services, deleted all services, deleted all api's / apps/ 
I have checked everything and cant seem to figure it out.

I run pm2 logs and get this error:

```
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/laye                                  r.js:95:5)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Route.dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/laye                                  r.js:95:5)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:349:14)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:                                  3)
parse-wrapper-0 (err): error: Uncaught internal server error. [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileData' of undefined] TypeError: Cannot                                   read property 'getFileData' of undefined
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at getHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers/FilesRouter.js:69:22)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/laye                                  r.js:95:5)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Route.dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-  server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/laye                                  r.js:95:5)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:349:14)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
parse-wrapper-0 (err):     at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:                                  3)
```

Any ideas?